# "database already closed" is shown using a custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I'm using a cursor with a custom adapter that extends SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
public class ListWordAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private int mLayout;
    private String[] from;
    private int[] to;

    public ListWordAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {

        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.mCursor = c;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        //public ImageView img;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView type;
        public TextView translate;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_row);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(to[0]);
                holder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(to[1]);
                holder.translate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(to[2]);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(from[0])));
            holder.type.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(from[1])));
            holder.translate.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(from[2])));
            // holder.img.setImageResource(img_resource);

        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And in the main activity I call it as:

```
adapter = new ListWordAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.row_list_words, mCursorWords, from, to, 0);
```

When a modification in the list is made, I call this method:

```
public void onWordSaved() {
        WordDAO wordsDao = new WordSqliteDAO();
        Cursor mCursorWords = wordsDao.list(getSherlockActivity());
        adapter.changeCursor(mCursorWords);
    }
```

The thing here is that this produces me this exception:

> 10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: database
>   /data/data/com.example.palabrasdeldia/databases/palabrasDelDia (conn#
>   0) already closed

Complete stack trace:

> 10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: database
>   /data/data/com.example.palabrasdeldia/databases/palabrasDelDia (conn#
>   0) already closed 10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2123)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:398)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:390)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:74)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:311)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:283)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:173)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   **> com.example.palabrasdeldia.adapters.ListWordAdapter.getView(ListWordAdapter.java:42)**
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2128) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1817) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1361) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1979) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1527)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1316) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9593) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1253) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2017) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 10-29 11:14:33.810:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
>   10-29 11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 10-29
>   11:14:33.810: E/AndroidRuntime(18659):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**If I use SimpleCursorAdapter directly instead of ListWordAdapter, it works fine. What's wrong with my custom adapter implementation?** The line in bold in the stack trace corresponds with: if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) inside getView method.

**EDIT**:

I have created a custom class to manage DB operations as open and close:

```
public class ConexionBD {
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public ConexionBD(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ConexionBD open() throws SQLException {
        this.dbHelper = DataBaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        this.database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (database.isOpen() && database != null) {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    /*Getters y setters*/
    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

}
```

And this is my DataBaseHelper:

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static DataBaseHelper sInstance = null;


public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
    // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DataBaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    ...
}
 ....
```

And this is an example of how I manage a query:

```
public Cursor list(Context context) {
        ConexionBD conexion = new ConexionBD(context);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        try{
            conexion.open();

            mCursor = conexion.getDatabase().query(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_WORD , null , null, null, null, null, Word.NAME);

            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }

        }finally{
            conexion.close();
        }

        return mCursor; 
    }
```

For every connection to the DB I open it and close it.

Comment: How did you implement `SQLiteOpenHelper` class? did you create an `open` and `close` method for get `SQLiteDatabase` and close it? your problem is for that you have not specified an `open` and `close` methods for `SQLiteDatabase` in your code? edit you question and add your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry the exception is "database already close", but is the same case.

Comment: what is `WordDAO ` class? and what are you using it for?

Comment: Im using the same schema in web scenario so I used DAO as an interface to tell what operations should been implemented independently of the DB manager. But this has nothing to do with the problem that Im facing.

Comment: I think your problem is in `finally`: you close your connection. Then adapter try use a closed cursor

Comment: @ramaral If I dont close the connection then I get another exception: 10-30 09:50:05.210: E/AndroidRuntime(23979): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT * FROM word ORDER BY name)

Comment: I can't see where this line are. My suggestion: maintain the db connection open all time but always close cursor after use it. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645245/2556111) how to deal with db and tables

Comment: @ramaral but where should I close the cursor? Im using a ListView and the onListItemClick, I set: Cursor cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);. It seems that I cant close the cursor because Im going to need it when a user clicks an item in my listView. By the other hand, I dont see any difference between the class that you are proposing and my conexionBD class.

Comment: If the cursor is used in a adapter close it in activity onDestroy event. The difference is the class that I suggest is Singleton, for many times it is used only one instance is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!. It was the method getView, specifically this line as the error mentioned:

```
if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position))
```

I shouldn't use the cursor of the constructor, instead I have to get a new one from the position:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
```

This way I dont try to access an cursor already close by the database. All the code that I posted was right, the only thing was the cursor that I was using inside the getView method.