# Get cell Values from Tablelayout & put it in another activity for update

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm a newbie to Android. 
My requirement is, In ViewAll activity, when I click on the particular row/cell, it has to Get that cell Values from Tablelayout and put it in another activity for updating those values. Please correct me if i did any mistakes.
I have attached the layout & class files FYR.

ViewAll.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/maintable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" 
    android:shrinkColumns="1">
   </TableLayout>
```

ViewAll.java

```
package com.bharath.myidentity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewAll extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String fname,lname,email;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB1",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        try{

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String UserID ="";
            if(extras !=null)
            {
                db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyIdentity",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                UserID = extras.getString("Id");
                String UserName = extras.getString("UserName");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),UserID+UserName, 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
//              TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
                TableLayout tableLayout =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
                tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

                //tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
                TableRow tableRow;

                TextView textHeading,textView,textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5;
                tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                tableRow.setClickable(true);
                //tableRow.setOnClickListener(this);
                //Heading - Starts Here
                textHeading=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textHeading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                //textHeading.setClickable(true);
                textHeading.setText("Hi, "+UserName);
                textHeading.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                textHeading.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                textHeading.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                tableRow.addView(textHeading);

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                //Heading - Ends Here

                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from identities where userid='"+UserID+"'", null);
                int count= c.getCount();
                c.moveToFirst();

                tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                tableRow.setClickable(true);
                textView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                //textView.setClickable(true);
                textView.setText("Sl.");
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                tableRow.addView(textView);

                textView4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                //textView4.setClickable(true);
                textView4.setText("Title");
                textView4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                textView4.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                tableRow.addView(textView4);

                textView5=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                //textView5.setClickable(true);
                textView5.setText("Descriptions");
                textView5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView5.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                textView5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                tableRow.addView(textView5);

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                 for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
                 {
                     tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                     tableRow.setClickable(true);
                     textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                     textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                     textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                     textView2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
                     //textView2.setClickable(true);
                     textView3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                     //textView3.setClickable(true);
                     textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description")));
                     textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                     textView2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                     textView3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                     tableRow.addView(textView1);
                     tableRow.addView(textView2);
                     tableRow.addView(textView3);
                     tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                     c.moveToNext() ;
                 }

                 setContentView(tableLayout);
                 db.close();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loaded Completely...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        final TableLayout contact_table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        final View row=contact_table.getChildAt(2);
        row.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final TableLayout contact_table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
            final View row=contact_table.getChildAt(2);
            int row_id;
            row_id=0;
            row_id=contact_table.indexOfChild(row);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),row_id + " Row ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
}
```

Welcome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/Welcome" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="@string/id" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:onClick="Insert"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextDescr"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/viewall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextId"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextDescr"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextDescr"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextDescr"
        android:text="@string/descr" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDescr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:onClick="Insert" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Welcome.java

```
package com.bharath.myidentity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Welcome extends Activity {
// This is the Screen for  - Entering Identities & "I WOULD LIKE TO GET VALUES HERE FROM ViewALL ACTIVITY"
    String Title="",Descr="";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String UserID ="";
    String UserName ="";
    public Welcome() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras !=null)
        {
            UserID = extras.getString("Id");
            UserName = extras.getString("UserName");
            Resources res = getResources(); 
            String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.Welcome), UserName);
            TextView TextUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextUserName.setText(text);
            if (UserID.equals(""))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyIdentity",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE login");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS identities(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 

AUTOINCREMENT,userid VARCHAR,title VARCHAR,description VARCHAR, FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES login(id));");
                db.close();
            }
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }
    }


    public void Insert(View view)
    {
        try {
              EditText edittextTitle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
              EditText edittextDescr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDescr);

              Title=edittextTitle.getText().toString();
              Descr=edittextDescr.getText().toString();
              if (Title.trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter UserName...", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                edittextTitle.setFocusable(true);
                //here, return is like a break & it will skip the TRY block...
                return;
              }
              if (Descr.trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Password...", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                edittextDescr.setFocusable(true);
                return;
              }
              if ((!Title.trim().equals("")) && (!Descr.trim().equals("")))
              {         
                db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyIdentity",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                //System.out.print(UserName);
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                String UserID ="";
                if(extras !=null)
                {
                    UserID = extras.getString("Id");
                    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from identities where userid='"+UserID+"' and 

title='"+Title+"'", null);
                    if (c.getCount()==0)
                    {   
                        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO identities(userid,title,description) 

VALUES('"+UserID+"','"+Title+"','"+Descr+"');");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identity Saved Successfully...", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identity Already Exist for this 

User...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identity Already Exist for this User...", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                db.close();
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
     public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewAll.class);
        intent.putExtra("Id", UserID);
        intent.putExtra("UserName", UserName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_identity, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If any details needed pls ask me I'll provide.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why `TableLayout` to show database rows? Instead use `ListView` or `GridView`

Comment: Hi Ramaral, first of all thnks for ur reply... can you give me example for this...how to display values into listview/grid with edit option..so when i click edit it has get values from listview/grid and put it into corresponding textboxes in welcome activity to update..

Comment: Start by learning how to use SQLiteOpenHelper class, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645245/2556111. Then search for ListView and CursorAdatper. It's not as complicated as it seems and it is essential for starting developing Android applications using sqlite.