# The constructor SQLiteOpenHelper() is undefined

Tags: android, undefined, android-sqlite

So when I launch the app I get the fatal exception main saying that there is no empty constructor.
Then when I add the empty constructor it gives me that "The constructor SQLiteOpenHelper() is undefined" error.

This is my first app ever so I have no clue what to do.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.lightalarmclock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class writeAlarm extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS = "positions";
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    private DbHelper ourHelper;

    private static String pos1 = "0";
    private static String pos2 = "0";
    private static String pos3 = "0";
    private static String pos4 = "0";
    private static String timeSet;

    private static int rep1 = 0;
    private static int rep2 = 0;
    private static int rep3 = 0;
    private static int rep4 = 0;
    private static int rep5 = 0;
    private static int rep6 = 0;
    private static int rep7 = 0;
    private static int repB;
    private static int repSet;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarmDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "alarmStack";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void updateVars() {
        SharedPreferences positions = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
        //TODO import from sharedPreferences to local vars
    }

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public DbHelper() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //writing to database
            if (rep1 >= 0 || rep2 >= 0 || rep3 >= 0 || rep4 >= 0 || rep5 >= 0 || rep6 >= 0 || rep7 >= 0) {
                repB = 1;
            } 
            else { 
                repB = 0; 
            }

            //setting time
            timeSet= pos4+pos3+":"+pos2+pos1;

            //Writing
            db.execSQL
            ("INSERT INTO TABLE alarmDB.alarmStack(alarm_time, alarm_repeat, rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5, rep6, rep7) " +
                "VALUES (" + timeSet + ", " + repB + ", "+ rep1 +", "+ rep2 +", "+ rep3 +", "+ rep4 +", "+ rep5 +", "+ rep6 +", "+ rep7 +")");

            //launch backToMain
            backToMain(null);
        }

        public static void backToMain(Context ctx) {
            // do some stuff here
            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void backToMain() {
        Intent j = new Intent(writeAlarm.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(j);
    }

    public writeAlarm (Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public writeAlarm open() {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html, there is no default constructor.

Comment: @natez0r as I wrote in the beginning, when I remove the constructo I get a runtime error saying "there is no empty constructor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For class `DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` you are doing this:

```
public DbHelper() {
    super();
}
```

If you look in the [Android docs for SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), there is no `SQLiteOpenHelper()` constructor so it is complaining.

Comment: When you say "there is no SQLiteOpenHelper() constructor", are you saying that the class SQLiteOpenHelper has no constructors at all, or are you saying there are no constructors that take zero parameters? Because clearly there are two constructors for that class. Not trying to be argumentative, I am simply a new Android Dev who is trying to learn.

Comment: @Brian The latter.  `super()` tries to call `SQLiteOpenHelper()` which doesn't exist.  The other constructor `DbHelper(Context context)` works because it calls `public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)`, which is a valid constructor.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Look at he public ocnstrucors and pass right parms

`SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)`

Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database.

`SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)`

Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database.

You need to use one of the above two constructors.  But you have

```
public DbHelper() { // remove this
        super(); 
    }
```

You already have

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Edit:

You are creating a constructor of `Activity` class which is wrong

```
public class writeAlarm extends Activity {
```

You have

```
public writeAlarm (Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }
```

I would suggest you to move this

```
 private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
```

to separate .java file

Comment: Hi, I've tried to stick to you're recommendations but now I get the error in 'writeAlarm()' saying "The constructor writeAlarm.DbHelper(Context) is undefined"

Comment: @user2979816 what is witeAlaram and where do you have DbHelper?

Comment: @user2979816 defintely there are too many issues for you address apart from the constructor error. i suggest you read the docs on activities and sqlite first before coidng

Answer (score 0):

Too many things!!

Remove this:

```
public DbHelper() {
    super();
}
```

And this:

```
public writeAlarm (Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}
```

At onCreate put this:

```
ourContext = this;
```

In

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
```

You must create the database.

[See this maybe help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19645245/2556111)

Answer (score 0):

I m showing one exmample For SqlLiteHelper

1)Creating class for sqlitehelper

> public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "myDatabase";

public static final String TBL_NAME = "myTable";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "Name";
public static final String COL3 = "Mobile";

public SQLHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(createTable Query);
    Log.d("tag", "Succesffull");
}

public void InsertData(String val1,String val2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL2, val1);
    cv.put(COL3, val2);
    db.insert(TBL_NAME, COL1, cv);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

After Created your class after calling 
//initialize SQLHelper class

**SQLHelper helper;**

//Simply pass your current activity

**helper = new SQLHelper(MainActivity.this);**