# Creating an android database - "Implicit super constructor SQLiteOpenHelper() is undefined for default constructor"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, constructor

I've been trying to create a database through SQLite, however it seems to have a problem with importing it. Here is my `Database.java`

I've had a look round and people have the same code as mine and theirs works.

the line import `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;` is underlined red and the error states:

**Implicit super constructor SQLiteOpenHelper() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor**

```
  package com.example.project;

import com.example.project.tableStudents.tableColumns;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int db_version = 1;
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, tableColumns.Database, null, db_version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I changed the import to import android.database.sqlite.*; and it seems to be okay now

Comment: Nevermind, I cleaned it and the errors back

Comment: The code you have posted here looks fine. I don't see anything that will cause the error that you posted. The fact that the line with the `import` statement gives this error is incredibly strange. The error has nothing to do with `import`. I suspect there is an inconsistency between the compiled and text versions of your code.

Comment: I just tried your code, no compile errors for me.

Comment: I dont get what I could do wrong, I created a class and made SQLite the superclass, that's literally it I don't understand what could go wrong within that

Comment: `tableColumns.Database` looks strange to me. Should it be `Database.tableColumns`? Is `tableColumns` declared somewhere? (This probably isn't related to your error, but it does indicate that you haven't shown us the **exact** code which you are compiling.)

Comment: tableColumns is an abstract class in a seperate class

Comment: it's just giving the name stored in the tableStudents class as "Database"

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?  Also, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Two suggestions (still unrelated to your question): 1. Class names should start with an uppercase letter. Variable and function names should start with lowercase. 2. Put the variable containing the name of the database file in the `Database` class shown here. I don't see a need to put this in a different class.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Unsure of what version of Java I'm using on it though

Comment: Right click on your project, select Properties.  Go to Java Compiler.  For Compiler compliance level, it should be `1.7`

Comment: Where do I define the explicit constructor the error message tells me to do? That's what is confusing me

Comment: I would propose to delete this class and write it from scratch. And give another name instead of Database.

Comment: The thing is, you can't really define a default constructor for a SQLiteOpenHelper, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575528/the-constructor-sqliteopenhelper-is-undefined    it's very strange that you are getting this error, and I can't recreate it with your code.  So, there is nothing wrong with the code, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Confusing, i don't know what to do as this is the only computer I have access to

Comment: First step, start a new test project, and add this class code to it.  If it works (which it should), start copying configuration/code from your real project to the test project in stages, and see when it breaks.

Answer (score -1):

i hade thesame problem and i fix it : go to the abstract classtableColumns and make all variabels static .

Comment: The class needs to define an explicit constructor.